# Inconsistencies when executing Hibernate update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I have a MQ listener which listens to messages and updates the status to DB. I have a setup where Hibernate session is managed by Spring.

Below is MQ listener configuration.

```
        <bean id="queue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
             <constructor-arg value="queuename" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="listenerBean" class="com.mypackage.Listener">
                <property name="service" ref="myService" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="listener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
                <constructor-arg><ref bean="listenerBean"/></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
                <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
                <property name="destination" ref="queue" />
                <property name="messageListener" ref="listener" />
                <property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionListener" />
                <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
                <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
        </bean>
```

On Java end to handle the MQ message,

```
public class Listener implements MessageDelegate{

        public MyService service;

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Serializable message) {
                service.process(message);
        }
}
```

The process method in service class calls the DAO methods to update the DB.

Below are hibernate properties used for the Spring sessionFactory bean `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache_db_custom.xml</prop>
          </props>
    </property>
```

This sessionFactory is injected into my DAO bean and I get my session using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Using this `session` I am using Criteria API to get the bean based on the unique value I get from MQ message and for the unique result I obtain, I change the status to success and I again call, `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to get `session` and call `session.update()` to update the DB.

There are no annotations on bean as I am using hbm files. It is a simple bean with no one-to-many or many-to-one mappings. There is no `@Transactional` annotation.

Below is the update snippet. I believe Spring takes care of transactions.

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    if(session != null && bean != null) {
       session.update(bean);
    }
```

I have a logger (added by me, log4j) for DB successfully updating and exception handling whenever the DB update fails.

Here comes the weird part.

I have come across a scenario in multi-threaded environment where the logs don't show any exception thrown by hibernate and logs show DB is successfully updated, however, the status is not updated. This happens only for some of the records, not all. There are records which are successfully updated. I am not able to find any data specific issue.

When I executed one of the records which failed to update using JUnit, it updated successfully.

Could someone let me know if I have missed anything on configuration end ?

Comment: Can you add your MQ listener code and tell us how many listeners are configured ?

Comment: @javaguy Updated MQ listener code in the question. There are 8 listeners on 8 JVMs distributed across 2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a design issue in your application i.e., basically, in the multithreaded JMS applications, when the consumer is listening with multiple threads then the messages will loose the order (with which the producer has produced) and you will find incorrect updates in the database (without any exceptions, we have faced the same issue some time back in our application) if you don't design the application carefully.

So to solve the problem, one way is that you need to have a business logic from the database side to check that record to be updated is the really the correct one (you need to handle this in a single transaction with proper locking). For example,if your application holds the `number_of_products` in the `products` database table (in an increasing order), then you need to check that the new update should be done only when the new message comes up with a higher value of products.

One another solution is, creating an entry layer like adapter (which should be single threaded) and generate a sequence number using some business logic (like for each `product_type` there will a sequence) and checking for that sequence number during the database update. If the sequence number is lower that the previous value, you should ignore the message as it is not the latest one i.e., the latest message has already been updated to the database.

Comment: Basically the unique Id received from MQ message is part of a process. This record was inserted into DB 1 or 2 days ago with status as `New`, so it definitely should be present in DB. I dont mind the order the MQ messages are consumed, as long as the corresponding records are updated with status as `Completed`

Comment: What are the other status in between apart from New and Completed ?

Comment: There is `In Progress`, but that is application specific. Basically, after changing to `New` there is some process, after which it updates to `In Progress`, then there is a delay. Then the application gets a message from MQ to update status to `Completed`. I see some of records with `In Progress` status, even though message have been received from MQ.

Comment: So the problem is when that 'some process' updates the record after the message update, then it overwrites the 'Completed' to 'In Progress' again.

Comment: There is no code to update it back to `In Progress` from `Completed`. The records from `New` only is changed to `In Progress`.

Comment: Think in Multithreaded world, so both the threads see the status as 'New' and one tries to update to 'Completed' and one tries to update to 'In Progress', but at the end, we can't guarantee which thread takes priority, so one will overwrite the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128936/discussion-between-prabhat-and-javaguy).